# Expand white pixels Image processing in python

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

If I open an image as the one below, is it possible to expand the white pixels?

[image]

[image]

Pseudocode:

```
image = Image.open("test.png")
image = image.convert("RGBA")
my_data = image.getdata()

new_data = []
for i in my_data:
    if i[0] == 255 and i[1] == 255 and i[2] == 255:
        #append white to new_data + to the pixels around
    else:
        new_data.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
```

Thank you

Comment: Did my answer help? If it did, can you please accept it?

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a dilation using `numpy` and [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

# Create and initialize image
image = np.zeros((21, 41), dtype=bool)
image[8:12, 18:22] = True

# Define structuring element and applying dilation
strel = np.ones((3, 3))
dilated = binary_dilation(image, structure=strel)
```

Answer (score 2):

This operation is called [dilation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilatation_(Bildverarbeitung)). Python has functions for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dilate function from **cv2**, and a bit of **numpy**:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('input.png',0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(img,kernel,iterations = 5)

cv2.imwrite('result.png', dilation)
```